# Current usage of crass

Tags: meaning

Crass referred to financial attitudes... a person was crass if they discussed money or one’s finances. Is this currently in use?

Comment: It's the same meaning but manners are not really on topic here. (Sorry, not my rule).

Comment: @Lambie perhaps this question could be considered a question about English language **usage**? Given that's what the U in ELU stands for, I think it's on-topic.

Comment: StLouisa - could you please narrow it down to US English vs. UK English, and give us some context?  Do you want the listener/reader to assume you're referring to someone or something as *crass* because of the money aspect?  I mean, to me, there are a variety of ways of being crass.  Is that okay with you?

Answer (score 1):

Not unheard of, but there are many people who wouldn't know what it meant, depending on education.

Comment: Please add some sources to support your answer.

Comment: Just going off personal experience, having many less educated friends and acquaintances in England.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still and currently in use.

A cursory [Google inquiry](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crass%22%20inurl:blog&tbs=qdr:m&tbm=nws&ei=3mvrWv0s4tKPBNjoqOgL&start=0&sa=N&biw=1536&bih=734&dpr=1.25) specifying "crass" within digitally published news articles, limited to the last 30 days shows an accurate usage of 10-12 examples, **though** this might be skewed given some recent US events.

Comment: None of the first page involves comments about a person's finances. There are crass claims, crass  motives and others.

Answer (score 0):

**crass**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crass)

> So crude and unrefined as to be lacking in discrimination and sensibility.

It can be used to describe many behaviors and subjects. This American article [Why Talking Openly About Money Is Crucial, Not Crass](http://Why%20Talking%20Openly%20About%20Money%20Is%20Crucial,%20Not%20Crass) discusses its use.  I anecdotally do remembers my 'elders' calling discussing money, religion, and heavens forbid anything about sex crass. I do not hear such these days.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I don't think there's a foregone conclusion that this particular question will be closed as being off topic.  But at any rate, I think a more tactful comment that explains the guidance more thoroughly would be more likely to change a participant's way of interacting with the site.